How to dynamically get all entities defined in a Quarkus service
I have a registry library, which is imported by each Quarkus service. The library registers a service and sends some information about it to a registry service. Currently the registry service receives such information as IP and the name of the service, but I want to extend the functionality so that the names of the entities (classes annotated with @Entity) used by the service are also sent.
One of the possible approaches is to use https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections in combination with @RegisterForReflection (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/29859)
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName);
Set<Class<?>> entityClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);

However, with this approach each service needs to specify the name of the package where entities are located (e.g in application.propertoes) which I want to avoid. The goal is to be able to get the names of all the entities defined in the class without forcing the service to provide the location of the entities. Is it possible and if yes, how this can be achieved?

Have you tried consulting the jpa metamodel? entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()?
